# MongoDB fatal error: runtime: out of memory

Tags: mongodb, import, mongoimport

i was trying to import a large collection in mongodb but everytime i try to import

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    3491368960 Jul 15 06:15 activity-june.json
mongoimport --db analytics --collection reports < activity-june.json
```

it gives me error like this:

```
fatal error: runtime: out of memory

goroutine 37 [running]:
runtime.throw(0xcba857)
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:520 +0x69 fp=0x7fd4984fea68 sp=0x7fd4984fea50
runtime.SysMap(0xc308100000, 0x100000000, 0x42b700, 0xcd7eb8)
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/mem_linux.c:147 +0x93 fp=0x7fd4984fea98 sp=0x7fd4984fea68
runtime.MHeap_SysAlloc(0xce3ea0, 0x100000000)
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/malloc.goc:616 +0x15b fp=0x7fd4984feaf0 sp=0x7fd4984fea98
MHeap_Grow(0xce3ea0, 0x80000)
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/runtime/mheap.c:319 +0x5d fp=0x7fd4984feb30 sp=0x7fd4984feaf0
MHeap_AllocLocked(0xce3ea0, 0x80000, 0x0)...
```

heres my disk space:

```
-bash-4.1#  swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-1                               partition   4128764 133416  -1
```

and heres my last query on my database, its not inserting anything.

```
> db.reports.find().count();
7
```

Comment: System don't have enough free space to restore database process. Free RAM to restore database.

Answer (score 3):

Kindly check on this

1) Your computer should be having 64 bit, if it 32 bit then we cannot import more than 2GB of data
2) Each of your document should not exceed 16MB

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/

also check this post,
https://forum.syncthing.net/t/fatal-error-runtime-out-of-memory/2190